# Docker cp chaning the owner of a directory

Tags: docker

I have a container deployed on 2 different hosts.

When I copy the folder /tmp/env to /opt/step-agent it works on host A but not on Host B.

I copy the folder whit this command:
`docker cp /tmp/env/ step-agent_1:/opt/step-agent/conf`

ouput of `ls -lah` in /opt of the container on host A:

```
total 18848
-rwx------ 1 jboss jboss 10751616 Mar 12 19:25 chromedriver
-rwxrwxr-x 1  2000  2000  8531750 Apr  8  2018 geckodriver
drwxr-xr-x 3 root  root      4096 Jul  1 12:49 google
drwxr-xr-x 1 jboss jboss     4096 Jul  4 09:54 jboss
drwxr-xr-x 1 jboss jboss     4096 Jul  4 09:54 step-agent
```

In this case it doesn't change the owner

But on Host B it changes the owner:

```
-rwx------ 1 jboss jboss 10751616 Mar 12 19:25 chromedriver
-rwxrwxr-x 1  2000  2000  8531750 Apr  8  2018 geckodriver
drwxr-xr-x 3 root  root      4096 Jul  4 09:06 google
drwxr-xr-x 1 jboss jboss     4096 Jul  4 09:55 jboss
drwxrwxr-x 1  1002  1003     4096 Jul  4 09:54 step-agent
```

it changes the owner to 1002:1003 but there isn't a user called 1002 in the /etc/passwd folder.

Why does this happen and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Very interesting question, but could you please fix the sentence `ll of /opt of the container on host A`? I don't understand what `ll of ` means.

Comment: On Host A could you issue a `id -u jboss` and `id -g jboss` and add the results to your question. And do the same for Host B?

Comment: Guess: It copies with numerical uids and gids, and they are not the same on host A and host B.